# how to reset file parse in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, reset, logfile

Many questions have been seen here in Stackoverflow on the similar subject like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573097/logstash-file-input-sincedb-path). But none of them helped to reset Logstash. I've used:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/var/log/nginx/access.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

I've read that `.sincedb` can be set. But as I don't have these files I think it is unnecessary to set a file path for that.

Is there any other place that I could easily reset logstash? Why such a simple method is so hard to do?

---

**EDIT1:**
I've also tried `sincedb_path` with `/dev/null` as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file) has been said. Again it read from today not from the beginning of log file.

Comment: ` Again it read from today` Is there any kind of log rotation? Your problem might come from there

Comment: @baudsp Yes I have but I also have some records from yesterday (10-07)

Comment: What I meant is that the content from yesterday got rotated in another log file. But apparently it's not the case

Comment: @baudsp I have log rotation in place, but inside of log file I have some records from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by hand by modifying the .sincedb file.

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files) :

> Sincedb files are text files with four columns:
>   1. The inode number (or equivalent).
>   2. The major device number of the file system (or equivalent).
>   3. The minor device number of the file system (or equivalent).
>   4. The current byte offset within the file.

So if you change the last number to zero to restart the file at the beginning.